# Restoring a Deleted User in the Site's Owners and Members Groups SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, restore, user, delete

I have accidentally deleted some users from the site's members and owners groups. How do I restore these users back to the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add them as rjcup3 says or recover the site from backup to a different URL and compare groups.  Those are the only options really.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit group membership by clicking Site Actions > Site Permissions > click the group > New > Add Users > select the users > click OK.

Comment: Actually i dont remember the users whom i deleted :(

Comment: Good luck buddy.

Comment: Sit around and wait for someone to start freaking out about why they don't have rights anymore? Quickly fix it and tell them it must have been a glitch?

Comment: LOL @rjcup3. I think we need a user recycle bin.